# openmp serial faster than parallel

Tags: c, openmp

The code is parallel but I don't know why it's slower than my serial and when I add the thread to like 7 to 10 the program also gets slower.

I've been trying to figure out what the problem is but it has been difficult for me

I made the for loop parallel but it seems like its not working. I am not receiving any error when I run my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int m; 
    int n;
    double tol;// = 0.0001;
    double tstart, tstop;

    int i, j, iter, nthreads;



    m = atoi(argv[1]);
    n = atoi(argv[2]);
    tol = atof(argv[3]);

    double t[m+2][n+2], tnew[m+1][n+1], diff, difmax,priv_difmax;

    printf("%d %d %lf\n",m,n,tol);
    printf("Enter the number of threads (max 10) ");
    scanf("%d",&nthreads);

    omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
    tstart = omp_get_wtime ();

    //** initialise temperature array*


    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)\
    default(shared) private(i,j)
    for (i=0; i <= m+1; i++) {
        for (j=0; j <= n+1; j++) {
            t[i][j] = 30.0;
        }
    }

    //*** fix boundary conditions***


    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        t[i][0] = 20.0;
        t[i][n+1] = 100.0;
    }
    for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
        t[0][j] = 10.0;
        t[m+1][j] = 140.0;
    }


    //** main loop**


    iter = 0;
    difmax = 1000000.0;
    while (difmax > tol) {
        iter++;

        // **update temperature for next iteration**


        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) \
        default(shared) private(i,j)
        for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
            for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
                tnew[i][j] = (t[i-1][j]+t[i+1][j]+t[i][j-1]+t[i][j+1])/4.0;
            }
        }

        // **work out maximum difference between old and new temperatures**

        difmax = 0.0;

        #pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i, j, diff, priv_difmax)
        {
            priv_difmax = 0.0;
            #pragma omp for schedule(static)
            for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
                for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
                    diff = fabs(tnew[i][j]-t[i][j]);

                    if (diff > priv_difmax) {
                        priv_difmax = diff;
                    }

                    //** copy new to old temperatures**
                    t[i][j] = tnew[i][j];
                }
                #pragma omp critical 
                if (priv_difmax > difmax){
                    difmax = priv_difmax;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    tstop = omp_get_wtime ();

    // print results

    printf("iter = %d  difmax = %9.11lf", iter, difmax);

    for (i=0; i <= m+1; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j=0; j <= n+1; j++) {
            printf("%3.5lf ", t[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    tstop = omp_get_wtime ();

    printf("time taken is %4.3lf\n", (tstop-tstart));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Anything can happen (except reliable results) when you write a parallel reduction with the reduction clause omitted.  You would want to achieve a simd reduction in the inner loop and a parallel reduction in the outer, if the loops aren't eligible for collapse.  A compiler may be able to a better job with auto-vectorization in the absence of questionable omp pragma.

Comment: Does that mean I have to add reduction

Answer (score 0):

I do not see obvious issues except perhaps in the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i, j, diff, priv_difmax)
{
    priv_difmax = 0.0;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
            diff = fabs(tnew[i][j]-t[i][j]);
                if (diff > priv_difmax) {
                priv_difmax = diff;
            }
                //** copy new to old temperatures**
            t[i][j] = tnew[i][j];
        }
        #pragma omp critical 
        if (priv_difmax > difmax){
            difmax = priv_difmax;
        }
    }
}
```

The reduction part, copying `priv_difmax` to `difmax`, should be moved out of the loop so that threads pass through the `critical` section only once, and not at each iteration of the outer loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i, j, diff, priv_difmax)
{
    priv_difmax = 0.0;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait //no need to wait after the loop
    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
            diff = fabs(tnew[i][j]-t[i][j]);
                if (diff > priv_difmax) {
                priv_difmax = diff;
            }
                //** copy new to old temperatures**
            t[i][j] = tnew[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Finish the loop first, then update difmax
    #pragma omp critical 
    if (priv_difmax > difmax){
        difmax = priv_difmax;
    }
} //Implicit barrier
```

Now, parallelization has an overhead cost and speedup may be expected for large values of m and n only. The problem you are considering is maybe too small. On way to reduce the overhead would be to merge the two `parallel` constructs so that the pool of threads does not have to be spawned twice. Or even better, put the while loop inside the `parallel` construct, so that we only have to synchronize existing threads at each iteration, rather than create and destroy them:

```
difmax=1000000.0;
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i, j, diff, priv_difmax)
while (difmax > tol) {

    // have one thread reset difmax and increment iter
    #pragma omp single nowait
    iter++,difmax=0.0;

    // loop to update tnew - distributed among threads
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) \
    default(shared) private(i,j)
    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
            tnew[i][j] = (t[i-1][j]+t[i+1][j]+t[i][j-1]+t[i][j+1])/4.0;
        }
    } //implicit barrier here

    // each thread resets its private difmax
    priv_difmax=0.0;

    // loop to compute difmax - distributed among threads
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
            diff = fabs(tnew[i][j]-t[i][j]);

            if (diff > priv_difmax) {
                priv_difmax = diff;
            }

            //** copy new to old temperatures**
            t[i][j] = tnew[i][j];
        }
    }

    // each thread now updates difmax if needed, one at a time
    #pragma omp critical 
    if (priv_difmax > difmax){
        difmax = priv_difmax;
    }

    // put a barrier here to make sure that diffmax have been updated 
    // before any thread tests the condition for next iteration of the
    // while-loop condition
    #pragma omp barrier
}
```

---

The best way to compare a how a code runs in serial and parallel is to compile it with and without OpenMP support (e.g. with gcc, compile with and without the -fopenmp compiler and linker flag). This will help pointing out whether the issue is actually with parallelization, or with other modification between the original serial code and the "parallel-ready" version.

The idea is to know where time is lost when going from *original serial code* to *parallel code (compiled without parallel support)* to *parallel code (compiled with OpenMP)*

Some preprocessing header needs to be used, because the compiler will not recognize functions like `omp_get_thread_num()` without OpenMP support. `omp_get_wtime()` should not be used either; since all your time leasurements are done out of parallel regions, there is no need to use that specific function, and a call to `time()` will be accurate (this requires to `#include <time.h>`).

```
// This part is necessary for the code to run whether it is compiled or not with OpenMP
#ifdef _OPENMP
   #include <omp.h>
#else
   # ifndef _ESCAPE_OMPENMP
      #define omp_get_num_threads() 1
      #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
      #define omp_get_max_threads() 0
      #define _ESCAPE_OMPENMP
   #endif
#endif
```

Comment: i made all the changes but my serial is still faster and i used a bigger range of problem which m was 500 and n was 500 also and mt tol was 0.001.

Comment: Values of n and m are large enough, parallelization should be faster. Did you compile the parallel and serial version with the same optimization flags?

Comment: yeah i did that, i used -O1 for both of them